# Datetime creates blank result

Tags: php, datetime, format

Well, I have this code here

```
$rowValue[$y] = '16/08/2013';
$replaceThis = array("/");
$rowValue[$y] = str_replace($replaceThis, "-", $rowValue[$y]);
```

this will produce an output with `string` datatype, '16-08-2013'

and when I try to do this

```
$rowValue[$y] = DateTime::createFromFormat('d-M-Y H:i:s e', $rowValue[$y]);
echo $rowValue[$y];
```

it doesn't work, or simply it just displays blank...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're doing it incorrectly you need to give your current/passed date format to `createFromFormat` method (i.e Y-m-d in your case) and than after creating DateTime object you can format it using `format` method.

```
$rowValue[$y] = DateTime::createFromFormat('d-m-Y', $rowValue[$y]);
echo $rowValue[$y]->format('d-M-Y H:i:s e');
```

[*DEMO*](http://ideone.com/yBQmZo).

Comment: I don't understand why ''d-M-Y H:i:s e' doesn't work.. but thanks, it's now working. Still 3 mins til I accept your answer tho

Answer (score 1):

Check the DateTime format you're using. From the docs:

http://www.php.net//manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php

'M' is used for "a textual representation of a month, such as January or Sept." You need to use 'm' or 'n' instead, which is used for a "numeric representation of a month, with or without leading zeros." Since your string representation has a leading 0, you'll want 'm'.

Your code should look like the following:

```
$rowValue[$y] = DateTime::createFromFormat('d-m-Y H:i:s e', $rowValue[$y]);
```

Answer (score 1):

> I don't understand why ''d-M-Y H:i:s e' doesn't work.. but thanks, it's now working. Still 3 mins til I accept your answer tho

it does not work because your string does not have time. You must supply the current format of your string which is "d-m-Y" in DateTime::createFromFormat().